# Crash on Ref::Release() in android cocos2d-x

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

I am working on cocos2dx v3.3.  Whenever images are released using Release or autorelease, then a random crash happens in Android, however it is working perfectly fine in iOS.

Can anyone help or guide me how to handle these crashes?

Answer (score 0):

cocos2d-x implements a OC-like reference counting scheme for memory management.
This kind of crash is usually caused by wrong reference count. When you `release` or `autorelease` a `Ref`, you should make sure that it has been `retain`ed before so that its reference count is not zero.

For further details, you can refer to the following code snippet from `CCRef.cpp` (*NOTE: the comments are more important*):

```
void Ref::release()
{
    CCASSERT(_referenceCount > 0, "reference count should be greater than 0");
    --_referenceCount;

    if (_referenceCount == 0)
    {
#if defined(COCOS2D_DEBUG) && (COCOS2D_DEBUG > 0)
        auto poolManager = PoolManager::getInstance();
        if (!poolManager->getCurrentPool()->isClearing() && poolManager->isObjectInPools(this))
        {
            // Trigger an assert if the reference count is 0 but the Ref is still in autorelease pool.
            // This happens when 'autorelease/release' were not used in pairs with 'new/retain'.
            //
            // Wrong usage (1):
            //
            // auto obj = Node::create();   // Ref = 1, but it's an autorelease Ref which means it was in the autorelease pool.
            // obj->autorelease();   // Wrong: If you wish to invoke autorelease several times, you should retain `obj` first.
            //
            // Wrong usage (2):
            //
            // auto obj = Node::create();
            // obj->release();   // Wrong: obj is an autorelease Ref, it will be released when clearing current pool.
            //
            // Correct usage (1):
            //
            // auto obj = Node::create();
            //                     |-   new Node();     // `new` is the pair of the `autorelease` of next line
            //                     |-   autorelease();  // The pair of `new Node`.
            //
            // obj->retain();
            // obj->autorelease();  // This `autorelease` is the pair of `retain` of previous line.
            //
            // Correct usage (2):
            //
            // auto obj = Node::create();
            // obj->retain();
            // obj->release();   // This `release` is the pair of `retain` of previous line.
            CCASSERT(false, "The reference shouldn't be 0 because it is still in autorelease pool.");
        }
#endif

#if CC_REF_LEAK_DETECTION
        untrackRef(this);
#endif
        delete this;
    }
}
```